# Image of quasiprojective variety under closed map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a regular map of projective varieties that is closed (in the sense that it takes Zariski closed sets to Zariski closed sets).  Let $V\subset X$ be a quasiprojective subvariety (i.e. locally closed and irreducible). Is $f(V)$ a quasiprojective subvariety of $Y$?

(I'm aware that under arbitrary regular maps, the image of quasiprojective need only be constructible, but I am assuming the map is closed).

(I doubt that this question is really at the level of Mathoverflow, but I asked it at math.stackexchange and got a small number of upvotes but no answer, so I thought I might try to slyly provoke one of y'all into answering before you close it.)

Comment: No, the map from the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a point $x$ back to $\mathbb{P}^2$ is closed(e.g. because this is morphism is projective, hence proper), but the image of a complement to the strict transform of a line passing through $x$ is $\mathbb{P}^2\setminus \mathbb{P}^1\cup\{x\}$ which is not locally closed.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you think there's a counterexample among projective space bundles (i.e. $X$ is the total space, $Y$ the base, and $f$ the projection)?

Comment: That restriction doesn't really change anything: given a projective morphism $f:X\to Y$ which comes with an embedding $i:X\to \mathbb{P}^n_Y$ of $Y$-schemes, a locally closed subscheme $V\subset X$ gives a locally closed subscheme $i(V)\subset \mathbb{P}^n_Y$ whose image under the projection $\mathbb{P}^n_Y\to Y$ coincides with $f(V)$, so any counterexample with a projective morphism(for instance, the one above) gives rise to a counterexample for a projection of the sort $\mathbb{P}^n\times Y\to Y$.

Comment: Thanks, I am not so familiar with these things, especially the modern language, so I'm having a little trouble understanding this.  Does what your saying amount to taking the graph of $f|_V$ in $V \times Y \subset X \times Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n \times Y$?

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users

Comment: Yes, you can put it that way(the last multiple of $Y$ is redundant, we’re just embedding $X$ into $P^n\times Y$ in a way that respects the maps to $Y$), your argument with the graph just shows that a morphism from a projective source is projective.

Comment: "Slyly provoking into answering before closing" isn't a good reason for a question.

Comment: @LSpice it looks like community took the bait in this case. Off-topic questions should be closed without revealing the answer to remove this incentive.